# Can't click allow or deny or even close on the flash "____ is requesting permission to store data" popup

Tags: flash

so im using goanimate on my ubuntu 12.10 quantal quetzal and whenever it autosaves flash asks for permission to store data and i cant click anything on the popup!

it does this for webcam/microphone flash popups too,please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem once, I don't remember how I solved it but it might be the way described in [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883238) forum. the idea is to go to [this](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html) site and set it to allow it to 'never ask again' (not ideal but well). I seem to remember an other way with going into the flash folder and removing a certain file, but I cannot remember, maybe I can find it or someone else can provide that answer...

ps. in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin/+bug/865672) is mentioned that the bug will not occure in unity 2d, or gnome fallback

Comment: that method may have worked for them,but i tried and it did nothing.thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: I also found [this site](http://ubuntudigest.blogspot.nl/2011/10/how-to-solve-flash-problems-on-ubuntu.html), I did not try it so it is at your own risk

Comment: oops,i derped,it seemed highly similar to another method,it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use tab key to navigate between tabs. You can add site to allowed list.

Comment: i added the site to the allowed list,still refuses to work.

Comment: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html go to that site and open Global Privacy Settings panel, allow the site.

Comment: its not on that panel,and there is only an always ask,and always deny.

Comment: I know that, it's a control panel for such settings. Mouse support disabled on linux for flash due to security reason, some say it's a bug. I allowed facebook from that link. You can choose ask always

Comment: Visit this page http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html and click previously visited sites, pick up your site in it and turn on allow radio button.